# No more possible to catch a TIMEOUT ERROR with Cordova Android 3.6.3

Tags: java, android, cordova-3

After migrating from Cordova 3.4.0 to 3.6.3, it seems now to be impossible to catch the TIMEOUT ERROR in my activity (when my web site does not respond for instance). In the 3.5 release notes, a new behavior has been added "Ignore multiple onPageFinished() callbacks & onReceivedError due to stopLoading()" and seems to be the cause.
Looking at closely to the source code of the 3.6.3 CordovaWebView java class, when the loadUrlIntoView method is called, if we meet the 'Timeout error method' we have:

```
public void run() {
me.stopLoading();
LOG.e(TAG, "CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!");
if (viewClient != null)
{ viewClient.onReceivedError(me, -6, "The connection to the server was unsuccessful.", url); }

}
```

but the line `me.stopLoading();` does : `viewClient.isCurrentlyLoading = false;`
and when the line `viewClient.onReceivedError(me, -6, "The connection to the server was unsuccessful.", url);` is called, the `onReceivedError` method of the CordovaWebViewClient java class is called but ignores the error due to `stopLoading()`:

```
if (!isCurrentlyLoading)
{ return; }
```

Thus, this method returns and the `super.onReceivedError()` is never called... and no posibility to catch the TIME OUT to display a specific page.

Please help,
Amp